# Is ANN architecture mesh topology exist?

Tags: neural-networks, architecture, hidden-layers

I'm just wondering if there's ANN architecture that looks like mesh topology at context of computer networking.

If exist or possible, is **layer** notion still applied?

Comment: I don't know if that's what you're looking for, but there are *graph neural networks* that model arbitrary network structures

Comment: Generally we need data to flow from input to output - for obvious reasons. You might make a graph-shaped network but then which way is input to output? Maybe you say it flows both ways and you run this two-way network for a few steps but then if we unpack that, it turns out each step is like a layer.

Comment: Can you give me example the graph you mean? And how it's eventually same (still have layers).